# reference primary key from another table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have to create 2 tables.
the first one

```
CREATE TABLE orders
( order_id number(10) NOT NULL,
  order_name varchar2(50) NOT NULL,
  payment_id number(10) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT order_id PRIMARY KEY (order_id),
);
```

and when creating the second one I got this error
ORA-02270: no matching unique or primary key for this column-list

```
CREATE TABLE payment
    (
      payments_id number(10) NOT NULL,
      payment_name varchar(50) NOT NULL,
      CONSTRAINT payments_id PRIMARY KEY (payments_id),
      FOREIGN KEY (payments_id) REFERENCES orders(payment_id)
    );
```

not sure what I'm doing wrong

please help

Comment: REFERENCES orders(**payment_id**)

Comment: It's pretty obvious - your foreign key points to ("references") a column in table ORDERS, but that is not the PK column of that table. In ORDERS, you declared ORDER_ID as the PK. Is the intent that PAYMENT_ID have unique (distinct) values in table ORDERS, and that it should be referenced by the second table? If so, you need to add a UNIQUE constraint on that column in table ORDERS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reference a `UNIQUE` or `PRIMARY KEY` column. The `payment_id` column does not have one of those constraints on it.

From the [Oracle constraint documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/constraint.html#GUID-1055EA97-BA6F-4764-A15F-1024FD5B6DFE):

> #### Foreign Key Constraints
>
> A **foreign key constraint** (also called a **referential integrity constraint**) designates a column as the foreign key and establishes a relationship between that foreign key and a specified primary or unique key, called the **referenced key**.

Instead, you can add an `order_id` column to your table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE orders(
  order_id   NUMBER(10)   NOT NULL,
  order_name VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT orders__order_id__pk PRIMARY KEY (order_id)
);

CREATE TABLE payment(
  payments_id  NUMBER(10) NOT NULL,
  payment_name VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
  order_id     NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT payment__payments_id__pk PRIMARY KEY (payments_id),
  CONSTRAINT payment__order_id__fk    FOREIGN KEY (order_id)
                                      REFERENCES orders (order_id)
);
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=b749370c4090ac790401533cc56b9b33)*

Comment: thanks all for replying,
I added this line to the orders creating script and it worked now

  CONSTRAINT AK_payment_id UNIQUE (payment_id),

Comment: @Simo51 It may work but you should consider whether it makes sense to do that? Given both constraints, then you can only have unique `order_id` and you can also only have unique `payment_id` in the same tables so there will be a one-to-one relationship between the two ids. In that case, why not just have a single `id` column and use it for both? But if you can have multiple payments for each order then it definitely doesn't seem to make sense.